# Does a PHP MongoClient to new MongoDB Wrapper Class Exist?

Tags: php, mongodb

According to the site below, the php class for MongoClient is being deprecated in favor of the new class (horribly confusingly named) MongoDB\Driver\Manager and or MongoDB class.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php

We've written a lot of code based on MongoClient and not terribly excited to see that the API functions like findOne(), insert(), find() will all need to be updated.

Has anyone written or know of a wrapper class that would allow us to not have to go in and update/rewrite all the code based on the MongoClient API functions to utilize the new MongoDB class?

Answer (score 0):

You can give [alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter](https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter) a spin.